# Query-parameter substitution fails

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have a repository which is about like the following one, where I'm using an annotated query with parameters. However when it comes to substitution, it fails with the exception: `org.neo4j.cypher.ParameterNotFoundException: Expected a parameter named custType1`

```
public class CustTypes {
    public static final String TYPE1 = "foo";
    public static final String TYPE2 = "bar";
}


public interface CustomQueryRepository extends GraphRepository<CustomEntity> {
    @Query(
        value = 
            " START c=node({0}) "
          + " WHERE c.type! = {custType1} "
          + "    OR c.type! = {custType2} "
          + "RETURN DISTINCT c, c.type AS compType",
        params = {
            "custType1", CustTypes.TYPE1,
            "custType2", CustTypes.TYPE2
    })
    Iterable<CustomMapResult> getTypes(List<Long> nodeIds);
}
```

I also already tried using a named parameter (with `@Param`) for `nodeIds` which made no difference.

What am I missing here, or can't I mix `Query.params` with method parameters?

I'm using spring-data-neo4j version `2.3.0.M1`

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I read in the reference documentation, it seems that the param attribute of @Query is only used when fields of entities are annotated with @Query.

EDIT:
I actually found an issues which documents this behaviour. I still think it should be mentioned somewehere in the SDN documentation:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-163

TLDR: Param attribute doesnt work in repositories(yet)

Comment: I second that it should be mentioned somewhere in the SDN documentation, because it is not obvious that `params` has no effect in `@Query`s, when used in repositories